# strongloop hasMany relation

Tags: strongloop

I have a `Service` model with the following JSON definition:

**common/models/service.js**

```
{
  "name": "service",
  ...
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "servicePrices": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ServicePrice"
      "foreignKey": "serviceId"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I have a second model ServicePrice

**common/models/service-price.js**

```
{
  "name": "service_price",
  ...
  "properties": {
    "price": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "service": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Service",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I try to get back a payload, something like this:

**http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/services**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Service-1",
    "id": 1,
    "servicePrices": [
      {"id": 1, "price": 10},
      {"id": 2, "price": 12}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Service-2",
    "id": 2,
    "servicePrices": [
      {"id": 3, "price": 14},
      {"id": 4, "price": 16}
    ]
  }
]
```

I would expect - that after migrating the models in Strogloop Arc - to have an extra column (service_id) in the service_price table. But it is not the case. And **http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/services** returns:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Service-1",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Service-2",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: did you know how the answer?